# Is there a way to place two images within a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I can use something like:

```
=IMAGE("http://emojidictionary.emojifoundation.com/img/emoji43.jpg",1)
```

to show a sun as single image. I know you can use '&' to concatenate strings (like `=C8&", "&D9`) or use JOIN or a few other methods. What I'd like is something like (and note this doesn't work):

```
=IMAGE("http://emojidictionary.emojifoundation.com/img/emoji43.jpg",1)&" + "&IMAGE("http://emojidictionary.emojifoundation.com/img/emoji444.jpg",1)
```

to show the sun the '+' and the sunglasses all in the same cell.

Is this possible or is a cell restricted to a single image?

Comment: So it sounds like you want to create an overlay of glasses on the sun?

Comment: No, I simply want the glasses next to the sun, in the same cell. The cell should resemble [ O + 8 ], where O is the sun, 8 is the glasses, and '+' is a string I inserted between them.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible to set two images in the same cell by concatenating the result of two IMAGE functions, but you could do this by adding the emojis directly in the cell:

[image]

You could copy the emojis from a web application that includes a feature to insert them or by copy them from a web page like http://emojipedia.org/.